# How to parse the first name of a sql string lname,fname middleinitial?

Tags: sql

I am trying to transform a Name column from :-

```
Name
---------------------
Brown,Charlie S
```

To be three separate columns:

```
FName
-------------
Charlie

MiddleInitial
-------------
S

LName
-----------
Brown
```

I have the following code:

```
SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name) + 1, CHARINDEX(',', Name + ',', CHARINDEX(',', Name) + 1) - CHARINDEX(' ', Name) - 1)
```

It is delivering the middle initial and last name correctly, but it is only returning the first letter of the last name.

How can I improve the code to return all the letters of the last name?

My list is thousands of names long, but is formatted the same as above for every line.

Comment: Which db you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will work for you, but worth a try may be::

```
 select SUBSTRING(@Name, CHARINDEX(',', @Name) + 1, len(@Name)- CHARINDEX(',', @Name)-2)
```

*** Full Functional Solution ***
Considering everything is dynamic in length i.e. firstname, middle name and last name can be of any length. Please note, I broke it in multiple statements to make it easy to understand.

```
 DECLARE @Name nvarchar(255),
        @FirstName nvarchar(255),
        @SecondName nvarchar(255),
        @MiddleName nvarchar(255),
        @WithoutSecondName nvarchar(255),
        @start int

 SELECT  @Name = 'Broooown,Charrrrlie Sroioiy', @start = CHARINDEX(',', @Name)

 SELECT @SecondName = SUBSTRING(@Name, 0,@start)
 SELECT @WithoutSecondName = SUBSTRING(@Name, @start + 1, len(@Name)- @start)
 SELECT @FirstName = SUBSTRING(@WithoutSecondName, 0 ,CHARINDEX(' ', @WithoutSecondName))

 SELECT @MiddleName = SUBSTRING(@WithoutSecondName, LEN(@FirstName)+2 ,LEN(@WithoutSecondName)-LEN(@FirstName))

 SELECT @FirstName, @MiddleName, @SecondName
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well. Do you mind walking me through how this works so well? I'm stuck on interpreting how the len - charindex(',',@Name)-2) works so well. I kept on trying to get the length of characters to select for the substring expression, but kept getting errors.

Comment: Let's start by taking this example of Brown,Charlie S. Here, 

Len - Full length of string including one comma and one space before middle initial.

CharIndex - The logic here is to get the Name after comma. So Len - CharIndex is the Total length of substring. But it will include blank space and middle initial as well.
So -2 is to remove that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It's helpful because I am finding I'll need to accommodate some variations in middle name lengths. I tried to up vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points yet. I will keep this on my radar to up vote when I get enough points.

Comment: Super awesome mate ! no worries.
Just remember to help someone out sometime. This is how I have learnt from StackOverflow and keep this good thing going on and on.

Comment: Will do. Do you happen to know if instead of the static -2 you could put in a dynamic character count? For example: Brown, Charlie Sr is entered then I would assume I could enter SUBSTRING(AD.Name, CHARINDEX(',', AD.Name) + 1, len(@Name)- (CHARINDEX(',', @Name)- (CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Name))))), but it no longer takes out the middle initial or middle name. I'm puzzled because in my head, the logic here is to get the start point after the comma and then count the characters up to the space as the -2 initially hard coded.